# Why (ftruncate+mmap+memcpy) is faster than (write)?

Tags: file, unix, optimization, mmap

I found a different way to write data, which is faster than normal unix `write` function.

Firstly, `ftruncate` the file to the length we need, then `mmap` this block of file, finally, using `memcpy` to flush the file content. I will give the example code below.

As I known, mmap can load the file into the process address space, accelerating by ignoring the page cache. BUT, I don't have any idea why it can fast up the writing speed.

Whether I write a wrong test case or it can be a kind of opti trick?

Here is the test code. Some of its written in ObjC, but no matter. `WCTTicker` is just a statistics class using `gettimeofday`.

```
//find a dir to test
NSString* document = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString* dir = [document stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDir"];

//remove all existing test
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dir]) {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dir error:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"fail to remove dir");
        return;
    }
}
//create dir to test
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil]) {
    NSLog(@"fail to create dir");
}

//pre-alloc memory
const int length = 10000000;
const int count = 100;
char* mem = (char*)malloc(length);
memset(mem, 'T', length);

{
    //start testing mmap
    // ftruncate && mmap(private) &&memcpy
    NSString* mmapFileFormat = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"privateMmapFile%d"];
    [WCTTicker tick];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:mmapFileFormat, i];
        int fd = open(path.UTF8String, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXO);
        if (fd<0) {
            NSLog(@"fail to open");
        }
        int rc = ftruncate(fd, length);
        if (rc<0) {
            NSLog(@"fail to truncate");
        }
        char* map = (char*)mmap(NULL, length, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        if (!map) {
            NSLog(@"fail to mmap");
        }
        memcpy(map, mem, length);
        close(fd);
    }
    [WCTTicker stop];
}

{
    //start testing write
    // normal write
    NSString* writeFileFormat = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"writeFile%d"];
    [WCTTicker tick];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:writeFileFormat, i];
        int fd = open(path.UTF8String, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXO);
        if (fd<0) {
            NSLog(@"fail to open");
        }
        int written = (int)write(fd, mem, length);
        if (written!=length) {
            NSLog(@"fail to write");
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    [WCTTicker stop];
}

{
    //start testing mmap
    // ftruncate && mmap(shared) &&memcpy
    NSString* mmapFileFormat = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sharedMmapFile%d"];
    [WCTTicker tick];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:mmapFileFormat, i];
        int fd = open(path.UTF8String, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXO);
        if (fd<0) {
            NSLog(@"fail to open");
        }
        int rc = ftruncate(fd, length);
        if (rc<0) {
            NSLog(@"fail to truncate");
        }
        char* map = (char*)mmap(NULL, length, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (!map) {
            NSLog(@"fail to mmap");
        }
        memcpy(map, mem, length);
        close(fd);
    }
    [WCTTicker stop];
}
```

Here is the test result:

```
2016-07-05 11:44:08.425 TestCaseiOS[4092:1070240] 
0: 1467690246.689788, info: (null)
1: 1467690248.419790, cost 1.730002, info: (null)
2016-07-05 11:44:14.126 TestCaseiOS[4092:1070240] 
0: 1467690248.427097, info: (null)
1: 1467690254.126590, cost 5.699493, info: (null)
2016-07-05 11:44:14.814 TestCaseiOS[4092:1070240] 
0: 1467690254.126812, info: (null)
1: 1467690254.813698, cost 0.686886, info: (null)
```

Comment: `write` is slower as it works with OS and libc I/O buffering while mmap goes to disk almost directly. The point is how much the overhead of file creating/truncating/etc. is bigger than that I/O buffering of `write`. You may win or lose depending on that.

Comment: @GMichael write is pure OS, not libc buffering, only OS buffering.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It depends on implementation. Even if you're correct, there is still OS buffering.

Comment: `write` use internal OS buffering, while `mmap` use virtual memory. With `mmap` you can write to memory (in general this is very fast), then you `unmap` and your process virtual memory is just released from its space, but the kernel get it and take the time to flush the data on disk on behalf the process.

Comment: @GMichael buffering is a tool to accelerate I/Os not to slower down, so it lacks of some good explanation on why O/S buffering seems to fail here. And no write is pure OS (at least on Unix systems)...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Buffering accelerates if and only if there are many "sort"/"small"/"simple" actions where we may benefit from pulling them together and eliminating some overhead. It makes things worse if we deal with one-time actions.

Answer (score 1):

You have `mmap()` without corresponding `munmap()`

From `mmap` manual page (linux)

> MAP_SHARED Share  this  mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible
>   to other processes that map this file, and are carried through to  the
>   underlying file. The file may not actually be updated until msync(2)
>   or munmap() is called.

Perhaps you should run your tests again so that there is a call to `munmap`:

```
char* map = (char*)mmap(NULL, length, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (!map) {
   NSLog(@"fail to mmap");
}
memcpy(map, mem, length);
munmap(map, length);
close(fd);
```

Comment: Exactly.  OP isn't measuring anything other than the `memcpy()`.  `mmap()` does not bypass the page cache.  Read what [Linux Torvalds has to say about `mmap()`.](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the munmap (or msync) added, I think this should be faster at least for big data transfers because write() results in a copy operation while mmap and access to the map do not.